# Complex Number, Simple Identity

Tags: complex-numbers

Does this expression:

(C + C*)/ 2 = C

imply

that C is always real?

Suppose C is complex: a+ib
and thus C* = a-ib

Then we end up with

a = C and a is real, thus C is always real if it equals (C + C*)/ 2

Comment: Yes, your argument is fine.

Comment: That's correct. Another way to write it is $c = \frac{1}{2}(c + c^*) = \Re(c) \in \mathbb{R}\,$.

Comment: If C is mean to be a complex number (rather than $\mathbb C$ which is the set of all complex numbers) and $C^*$ is meant to be the complex conjugate (usually written as $\overline {C}$) then, yes, for any complex number $z$ then $z + \overline{z} = 2Re(z)$ is always a real number.  By the way $z*\overline{z} = Re(z)^2 + Im(z)^2$ is also always a real number.

Comment: Um @dxiv, Am I missing something $c = \frac 12(c + c^*)=\Re(c)$ isn't usually true, is it?  Not if $c$ is complex?  Did you mean to say $c = \frac 12(c+\overline{c}) + \frac 12(c - \overline{c})=\Re(c) + i\Im(c)$?

Comment: @fleablood $c=\frac{1}{2}(c+c^*)$ is the premise of the exercise.

Comment: D'oh!!!.   Yes.  If $c = a + bi;a,b \in \mathbb R$ and $\overline c = a - bi$ then the $\frac 12(c + \overline c) = a = Re(c) \in \mathbb R$ for all complex numbers, so if $c = Re(c)$ then $c$ is a purely real number (and vice versa.  $c = \frac 12(c + \overline c) \iff c \in \mathbb R$)  (and furthermore $c =\frac 12(c - \overline c) \iff c$ is purely imaginary).  D'oh, to me for missing the actual question.

Comment: As a tangent,  I suppose a trivia question/trick question/puzzle would be what number is both purely real and purely imaginary? There is one.... but only one...

Comment: Yes your argument is fine and your dog too. Wait, did I say dog? Who brought the dog in?

Comment: Ok thx all mates :)